# Split hash in hash of array

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have three hashes that I would like to explode each one into a Hash of Arrays. Each one could be passed into a subroutine with a split function, but this requires the same subroutine to be called 3 times. I have tried to iterate through each hash and them split it but without success. Is it possible to do this without calling a subroutine? The code I have tried is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash1 = (
    A => "AAAAAAAAAA",
    B => "AAAAANAAAA",
    C => "AAAAAXAAAA",
    D => "AAXAAAAAAA",
    E => "AAAAAAAAAX",
);

my %hash2 = (
    F => "BBBBBBBBBB",
    G => "BBBBBBBBBB",
    H => "BBXBBBBBBB",
    I => "BBBBBBBBBB",
    J => "AAAAANAAAA",
);

foreach my $ref ( \%hash1, \%hash2 ) {
    while ( my ($key, $value) = each %$ref) {
        @{ $ref->{$key} } = split (//, $value );
    }
}

print Dumper %hash1;
```

but gives the warning:

```
Can't use string ("AAAAAAAAAA") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your mistake is that you are taking the value of the key `$ref->{$key}` which is `AAAAAAA` etc, and using it as a reference with the `@{ ... }` braces. You need to assign to `$ref->{$key}` directly.

Since you are splitting the original value into a list, you need an array to store it. You can do this either by using a named array, lexically scoped, or an anonymous array. My choice would be to use an anonymous array, but a named array might appear more readable:

```
foreach my $ref ( \%hash1, \%hash2 ) {
    while ( my ($key, $value) = each %$ref) {
        $ref->{$key} = [ split (//, $value ) ];  # using anonymous array
        # my @list = split (//, $value );
        # $ref->{$key} = \@list;                 # using named array
    }
}
```

This process would overwrite the original values, but I assume that is what you want.

A more direct way to achieve the same thing would be this:

```
$_ = [ split // ] for values %hash1, values %hash2;
```

Here we are (ab)using the fact that the elements in a `for` loop are aliased to the original variables, and simply overwriting the values the same way we did above.

If the compressed format is unwanted, a more verbose alternative would be:

```
for my $value (values %hash1, values %hash2) {
    $value = [ split //, $value ];
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice one-liner! Just out of curiosity, by "faster" do you mean execution time or coding time?

Comment: Besides the solution it also has nice explanations. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I agree, it makes it so much easier for people like me who are still learning `perl`. Thanks @TLP.

Comment: @NigoroJr Ah, that was a bad way to put it.. What I meant was "less typing", and "more to the point".

Comment: @TLP Thanks, saved me the time to write a benchmark :)

Comment: Note: It's possible to write the code as `$_ = [ split // ] for %hash1, %hash2;`.  However, this isn't good because it takes advantage of the fact that hash keys can't be modified.  Instead, one should use `values` call before each hash as a way of communicating intent.

Comment: @Miller I did not write the code that you implied that I wrote. I wrote `$_ = [ split // ] for values %hash1, %hash2;` It's in the revision history, if you are unsure.

Comment: @TLP I know.  In that line `values` works on `%hash1`, but the `for` loop actually iterates on the keys and the values of `%hash2`.  It just happens that perl doesn't throw an error when trying to modify the keys even though it probably should.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I correctly understood what you want to do, you can use [hash slicing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) and do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash1 = (
    A => "AAAAAAAAAA",
    B => "AAAAANAAAA",
    C => "AAAAAXAAAA",
    D => "AAXAAAAAAA",
    E => "AAAAAAAAAX",
);

my %hash2 = (
    F => "BBBBBBBBBB",
    G => "BBBBBBBBBB",
    H => "BBXBBBBBBB",
    I => "BBBBBBBBBB",
    J => "AAAAANAAAA",
);

foreach my $ref ( \%hash1, \%hash2 ) {
    my @keys = keys %$ref;
    @$ref{@keys} = map { [split //, $ref->{$_}] } @keys;
}

print Dumper \%hash1;
print Dumper \%hash2;
```

This is like writing:

```
foreach my $ref ( \%hash1, \%hash2 ) {
    my @keys = keys %$ref;
    foreach my $key (@keys) {
        my @arr = split //, $ref->{$key};
        $ref->{$key} = \@arr;
    }
}
```

just simpler.